# I want to give a parameter for a function from a value from with

Tags: sql-server-2005

```sql
WITH
EmpDetails(EmpCode)
AS
(
 SELECT EmpCode 
 FROM Employee.tblEmp_Demographics 
 WHERE RecordStatus='present' 
)  

    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpCode ORDER BY DateTaken DESC) AS RowNum,    
    (select GradeName From Master.GradeMaster where GradeCode=Grade And Deleted=0) As Grade,    
    SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY Grade) AS EmpAmount,
    SUM(DependentAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY Grade) As DepAmount,
    0 As CheckNo 
    from [dbo].[SELECT_AIRTICKET_DETAILS_BY_DATE](EmpDetails.EmpCode,getdate(),1) WHERE YEAR(DateTaken)=year(getdate())
```

But i get an error

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 11 The multi-part identifier "EmpDetails.EmpCode" could not be bound.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue is a result of you passing a column `EmpDetails.EmpCode` name to the table-valued function, instead of a single value. You could try this instead:

```
DECLARE @EmpCode nvarchar(100);

SELECT TOP 1
       @EmpCode = EmpCode 
  FROM Employee.tblEmp_Demographics
 WHERE RecordStatus='present';

select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpCode ORDER BY DateTaken DESC) AS RowNum,    
(select GradeName From Master.GradeMaster where GradeCode=Grade And Deleted=0) As Grade,    
SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY Grade) AS EmpAmount,
SUM(DependentAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY Grade) As DepAmount,
0 As CheckNo 
from [dbo].[SELECT_AIRTICKET_DETAILS_BY_DATE](@EmpCode,getdate(),1) WHERE YEAR(DateTaken)=year(getdate());
```

If you want results for multiple values from the `Employee.tblEmp_Demographics` table, you could iterate through each value (probably not best), or modify your table-valued function to return a result set with all EmpCode values, and then add a `WHERE` clause to filter the data as needed.

---

***Edit***

Something like this perhaps - note the modified function that returns all EmpCodes & has one less parameter:

```
select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpCode ORDER BY DateTaken DESC) AS RowNum,    
(select GradeName From Master.GradeMaster where GradeCode=Grade And Deleted=0) As Grade,    
SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY Grade) AS EmpAmount,
SUM(DependentAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY Grade) As DepAmount,
0 As CheckNo 
  FROM [dbo].[SELECT_AIRTICKET_DETAILS_BY_DATE](getdate(),1) AS [Tickets]
 INNER JOIN Employee.tblEmp_Demographics
         ON tblEmp_Demographics.EmpCode = [Tickets].EmpCode
        AND tblEmp_Demographics.RecordStatus = 'present'
 WHERE YEAR(DateTaken) = year(getdate());
```

With this solution, the function returns all EmpCodes, but we filter out the unnecessary ones by performing an `INNER JOIN` on the `Employee.tblEmp_Demographics` table.

Comment: Actually i want to give a value from Employee.tblEmp_Demographics as a parameter for the funtion

Comment: The first `SELECT` statement gets the value from the `Employee.tblEmp_Demographics` table & saves it in the `@EmpCode` variable that is subsequently passed to the `[SELECT_AIRTICKET_DETAILS_BY_DATE]` function in the first parameter.

Comment: its is needed for all the empcodes in Employee.tblEmp_Demographics

Comment: I've updated the answer to include an example of you would call a modified version of the table-valued function. If you cannot modify the function for some reason, then I think that your only other alternative would be to recursively iterate through each value in the `Employee.tblEmp_Demographics` table. This is not the best method though - SQL Server & recursion are not a good mix.